# mapping not updated

Tags: solidity, truffle, mapping, truffle-contract

I'm testing a very primitive contract using mapping.

```
contract PhysicalContract {
    
    uint numContracts;
    
    mapping (address => uint) contracts_test;

    function newDeal(address adr, uint value) public{

        contracts_test[adr] = value; 

        numContracts++;
    }
}
```

The variable **numContracts** is successfully updated when I call newDeal(..) but not the mapping **contracts_test**.. It keeps desperately empty.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you test it but I wrote a function that shows it is actually not empty.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;  
    
contract PhysicalContract {
      
    uint numContracts;    
    mapping (address => uint) contracts_test;
    
    function newDeal(address adr, uint value) public {
        contracts_test[adr] = value; 
        numContracts++;
    }
        
    function indexE(address adr) public returns (uint) {
        return contracts_test[adr];
    }
}
```

Using REMIX editor, I first use `newDeal` to add values. Based on the address I use, I can return the corresponding `uint` of `contracts_test`.

Comment: Hi, Yes - you're right - it;s actually working fine when I test it on Remix. But when I test it externally on Ganache, it doesnt show anything - I guess it's maybe a visualization issue on the Ganache contract inspector.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing it. I would appreciate it if you can accept the answer.

Comment: thanks - Yes - I confirm, the problem comes from the Truffle contract inspector - it doesnt reflect correctly the mapping

Comment: You are welcome!