# why is storage empty in Ganache for a mapping field?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets

I have a smart contract which uses a `mapping` field as its state variable. It should be `storage` by default.

```
contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}
```

I am able to call `sendCoin` from web3 frontend and I am able to see the transaction events in Ganache UI. However, I don't understand why the storage is empty as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solidity, mapping is a key-value storage and act as hash tables that consists of key-value pairs. In your mapping, you pass in the address of the sender and return the number of coins corresponding to that address. The address acts as the key and the number of coins act as the value. This hashing is one-way, which means one cannot find out the key from the hash. Finding works when you give the key to the mapping and the mapping finds the corresponding hash. After finding the hash, mapping does a de-hash to find its original value. However, Ganache does not have the hashing key so it cannot do the de-hash, and therefore it returns an empty storage for a mapping field.

Comment: thanks for explaining. Does it work for all mapping variable? is there a way to remove hash on the value in a mapping variable?

Comment: I haven't tried for all mapping variables. What you can do instead is call your getBalance() function to see the balance instead of viewing the mapping storage in Ganache UI.

Comment: My answer may be one of the reasons why the storage is empty in Ganache for a mapping field. Other reasons I found may be due to truffle (if you're using it). See: "https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91906/mapping-not-updated" and "https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2889".